# Context SaveChanges does not work, using EF Code first , datagridview and bindingsource

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Why would my data not be saving?
Db is of type `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

When I load the grid I call

```
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = Db.People.Where(e => e.LastName.Contains("e")).ToList() ;

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;
```

When I Save the data I call

```
this.bindingSource1.EndEdit();

Db.SaveChanges();
```

I don't get an error, but the data does not save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is
Db.People.Where(p => p.LastName.Contains("e")).Load();
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = Db.People.Local.ToBindingList();